# Форматирование в SQLite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

1.Обьясните разницу между данными функциями:

```
char *sqlite3_mprintf(const char*,...);
char *sqlite3_vmprintf(const char*, va_list);
char *sqlite3_snprintf(int,char*,const char*, ...);
char *sqlite3_vsnprintf(int,char*,const char*, va_list);
```

2. Чем отличается `'%q'` от `%q`?

3.Отличия между аргументами типа `"%q"`, `"%Q"`, `"%w"`, `"%z"`.

Comment: Вот что бывает, когда до хранимок SQLite допускают человека не владеющего основами Си :)

Comment: @Barmaley, студент это почти человек)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитесь пользоваться документацией, [там все есть, полный ответ на Ваш вопрос](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html).

Эти Функции являются обертками над стандартными функциями С библиотеки для форматированного вывода [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) и [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). Соответственно `sqlite3_mprintf` и `sqlite3_vmprintf` для `printf`, и `sqlite3_snprintf` и `sqlite3_vsnprintf` для `sprintf`.

Первым отличием является способ передачи аргумента, либо перечислением через запятую, либо сишным списковым типом `va_list`. Вторым отличием является то, что sprintf помимо форматированного вывода еще сохраняет результат в буфере второго строкового аргумента для дальнейшего использования.

Аргумент `%q` работает как `%s`, но в работе удваивает `'` экранируя его.

Аргумент `%Q` работает как `%q`, но не удваивает `'`.

Аргумент `%w` работает как `%q`, но работает с двойными кавычками, а не одинарными.

Аргумент `%z` работает как `%s`, но еще вызывает `sqlite3_free()` на входную строку.